# adding observables to model during runtime. but ko.mapping.toJS doesn't return them

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

js and the knockout mapping plugin

my problem is this:

i have model and i am adding observables to it during runtime like so:

```
viewModel[value] = new ko.observable(valueFromTextBox);
```

this works ok and the observables are binded to the screen and this part works fine
the problematic part is when i try to take that model and convert it to JSON like so:

```
var JSON = ko.mapping.toJS(page.model);
```

when i debug this i see that page.model has all the new observables. but my final JSON has only the ones who were in the model to begin with. not the ones added later in runtime. 
what is the correct way to add observables during runtime?

thanks

EDIT:

I will describe my entire scenario and then post my solution as an answer.

I am using ASP.Net MVC, i created a view model then made an ajax call to receive my actual model form the server. then use:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(model, page.model);
```

after that the binding occurs later when the user adds new fields i used:

```
viewModel[value] = new ko.observable(valueFromTextBox);
```

and in the end before sending it back to the server i used:

```
 var JSON = ko.mapping.toJS(page.model);
```

in which point the added fields were not present in the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after debugging

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(model, page.model);
```

i realized the function reads the values in the dictionary

```
    __ko_mapping__.mappedProperties
```

which is creted during the use of the toJS function

```
var JSON = ko.mapping.toJS(page.model);
```

anyway because my new added observables were not present in the `__ko_mapping__.mappedProperties` dictionary they 
were also not present in the JSON object returned to me using the ko.mapping.toJS function
so what i did to make it work is this:

```
viewModel[value] = ko.observable(valueFromTextBox);
viewModel.__ko_mapping__.mappedProperties[value] = true;
```

I add an observable to my model but update my mappedProperties dictionary as well 
and that's it. now when calling `ko.mapping.toJS` my entire model is returned as a JSON object including my added observables.

I realize this is probably not the most elegant way of doing it. but it sure does work great.

Comment: Did you found better way to do that? I do the same but it's look little tricky for me

Comment: no i did it like so. and it runs like this for a few months already with no problems. it really do feel strange. the mapping plugin should have some kind of support for it built in. that would be best

Comment: I found something: you can user ko.mapping.fromJS(from, mapping,to) and I pass {include:[value1,value2]} as mapping object. It's add this values to __ko_mapping__.mappedProperties

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean .toJSON rather than .toJS?

This situation worked for me, although I don't think you should use "new", it should just be:

viewModel['PropertyName'] = ko.observable(value);

Actually both ways worked for me, with and without new, but in all the documentation it's used without, like a factory method. Could you create a fiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: ok ill try without the new. and no.. the function is called toJS

Comment: OK i switched to toJSON my bad it was toJS. and i removed the new. but no help.. :( maybe i don't have the latest version of knockout and knockout mapping. ill try to download again

Comment: I entered the mapping debug. and in this function: visitPropertiesOrArrayEntries there is a: unwrappedRootObject[mappingProperty].mappedProperties and the mappedProperties only contains the first initiated properties of the model with the newly added ones... any idea?

Comment: I think the best approach is to try to isolate what is different in your setup to a basic fiddle which works. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/VKFgT/3/ Does that capture the way you're doing it?

Comment: I will edit my question so it will fit the entire scenario of what I was trying to do. also i figured out a solution... its not the nicest but ill post it anyway because it does work.